# Alternative way to get meta tags from url

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using script to get meta tags from url:

```
function post_updated_set_og_image( $post_id ) {

    $url = get_field('link', $post_id);
    $page_content = file_get_contents($url);

    $dom_obj = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom_obj->loadHTML($page_content);
    $meta_val = null;

    foreach($dom_obj->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {

      if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image'){ 

      $meta_val = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'og_image_src', $meta_val);

}}
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_updated_set_og_image' );
```

It works good only on localhost, server gives me error:

> Warning: file_get_contents($url): failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in ...

Is the alternative way to get meta tags from url, how to do this or how to fix code above? I've checked php options and allow_url_fopen is ON.

Comment: It's possible the URL in `$url` has blocked your server from accessing it.

Comment: Hi @adkoski, what are you really trying to achieve?. It seems to me you are loading an external URL, and then scraping the DOM object to find the meta image. It seems to me that rather than scraping the URL you should be quering down in on the post object to determine this information.

Comment: .. and besides, file_get_contents needs a directory, not a url, then it should work. But, as emeraldjava said ...